# Error: Creating Tab-Navigation programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tabbar, navigationbar

Excuse if this problem is posted already..

I want to create combination of TabBar and NavigationBar programmatically using XCode 4.2 & iPhone SDK 5.0

It produces visual as expected..but when a TabBarItem is pressed(taped) to change to its corresponding view, it is producing error: **[__NSCFString _tabBarItemClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Here is the implementation of the **AppDelegat**

```
#import "ApplicationDelegat.h"
#import "BrightnessController.h"


@implementation ApplicationDelegat

@synthesize window;
//@synthesize bControl;



- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    UITabBarController *tbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        //self.bControl = [[BrightnessController alloc] initWithBrightness:i];
        BrightnessController *bControl = [[BrightnessController alloc] initWithBrightness:i];

        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: /*self.bControl*/bControl];

        nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        [controllers addObject: nav];
        //bControl.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem  alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" image:nil tag:i];
        //tbarController.navigationController.delegate = self;
    }

    tbarController.viewControllers = controllers;
    tbarController.customizableViewControllers = controllers;
    tbarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    tbarController.delegate = self;

   // NSCFString
    //tabBarItem

    // Set up the window
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.window addSubview:tbarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

@end
```

I don't know why it happens and how to recover it..
Somebody help me.

If more detail is required, I can provide the source code...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code as a start - that could help. how are you creating the tab bar and assign it all the views?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController; 7:20
switch(mytabbar.selectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab1_sel.png"]];
        [imageView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab2.png"]];
        [imageView3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab3.png"]];
        [imageView4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab4.png"]];
        [imageView5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab5.png"]];
        break;

    case 1:
```

you can use this method and change on each tabbar click index

Answer (score 1):

Two issues I see...

1. You assign the view of the `tabBarController` as a `subView` of the window. This is incorrect. You need to set the `rootViewController` of the window to be the `tBarController`.
2. Are you implementing the tab bar's delegate method `tabBar:didSelectViewController:`? Your error message says you're trying to send a `tabBar`-related method to an `NSString`. I suspect it's due in part to point (1). Try:

   self.window.rootViewController = self.tBarController;

Comment: @jnstone       1. You are correct. 2. I am not implementing tabBar:didSelectViewController & 1.     Thanks a ton jmstone, it is done. I am newbie in iPhone App development, this is why these mistakes. Thanks again.

Comment: @jnstone- though this problem is solved this way.. You've told that assigning the view of the tabBarController as a subView of the window is incorrect.. [**Here**](http://www.myfirstiphoneapplication.com/2009/11/tabbar-together-with-a-navbar-programmatically/) I've got an example that works fine with both (as subView & rootViewController).. you can test. So, can you explain, 1. Why doing that is illegal? 2. Why it is working on the example got from the link? Thanks.

Comment: It's not so much that it's illegal. Obviously you can do it. You just destroy the integrity of the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I typically prefer creating another tabbarview class that handles all the different view controllers, in which case, the app delegate will look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];        
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController.myTabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return;
}
```

And in ViewController I do this:

Header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITabBarController *myTabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *myTabBarController;
```

And in the implementation file:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

    exerciseViewController *viewController1 = [[exerciseViewController alloc] init];
    viewController1.title = @"Exercise";
    viewController1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Exercise" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inbox.png"] tag:0];
    UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];        


    bookViewController *viewController2 = [[bookViewController alloc] init];
    viewController2.title = @"Book";
    viewController2.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Book" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inbox.png"] tag:1];
    UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];


    askViewController *viewController3 = [[askViewController alloc] init];
    viewController3.title = @"Ask";
    viewController3.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ask" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inbox.png"] tag:2];
    UINavigationController *thirdNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];


    workshopViewController *viewController4 = [[workshopViewController alloc] init];
    viewController4.title = @"Workshop";
    viewController4.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Workshop" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inbox.png"] tag:3];
    UINavigationController *fourthNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController4];

    myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    myTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController, fourthNavController, nil];    


}
return self;
}
```

This is just an example...and I think it's the right way to do that.

Comment: @NiD - would be great if you could check the answer and/or upvote. thanks!